# Overriding keys from machine.config to web.config

Tags: asp.net

I need to move a key from machine.config to web.config. Below is the setting in machine.config.

```
<commonsettings>
    <setting environment="dev">
      <common>
          <value1>myValue1</value1>
          <value2>myValue2</value2>
          <value3>myValue3</value3>
      </common>
    </setting>
</commonsettings>
```

I have above mentioned setting defined in machine.config currently ( 3 keys - value1, value2, value3) , and I want to have only value1 declared in web.config.

I declare only value1 setting, but it does not work. The secion just recognizes only value1. I can not access value2, and value3 declared in machine.config

Below is what I did in web.config.

```
<commonsettings>
    <setting environment="dev">
      <common>
          <value1>myValue1</value1>
      </common>
    </setting>
</commonsettings>
```

What I want is that web.config performs some inheritance instead of overriding the whole section.

Can somebody please help me resolving this ?

Comment: Are you trying to manually move these configuration settings over (for example, with Notepad and copy/paste) or are you trying to do it from code?

Comment: I am trying to do without code changes, just copy/paste.

Comment: You have not explained where your error is coming from. You just said "it does not work". What specifically is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: What I want is, whenever code tries to pick Value1, it should come from web.config, but Value2 and Value3 should come from machine.config

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in your code
I assume you are defining  the type of the handler in your machine.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
      <section name="commonsettings" type="YourConfigSectionHandler, YourLibrary, Version=1.1.0.0"/>
 </configSections>
<!-- More configuration-->
<configuration>
```

And creating a class of that type inside your app:

```
public class YourSectionHandler : IConfigurationSectionHandler
{
    public object Create( object parent, object configContext, XmlNode section )
    {
        //your code to handler the configSection
    }
}
```

If you see the Create method has an argument `object parent`. It will contains the configuration of the parent config.

I suposse you have only a machine.config and a web.config.

1. Once the app launches, it will try to parse `machine.config/configSection/commonsettings/` ( section  should be declared there ) and the `Create` method will get called with a `null` parent.
2. Later your app's config will get parsed,and `Create` method will get called again. Now, the `parent object` parameter will hold the value of the previous step parse result.